# How to find similarity between two strings with function using python

Tags: python, string, similarity

These are two strings

```
string1 = 'SUTURE SILK 30 INCHES(75CM) 3-0 BLK'
string2 = 'SUTURE NON-ABSORBABLE PERMA-HAND SIZE 3-0 L'
```

I want output like

```
0.801452
```

how I can do this by using function

Comment: What would be your definition of "similarity"

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to get the Levenshtein Distance, without any aditional dependency you can do something like this:

```
def levenshteinDistance(s1, s2):
if len(s1) > len(s2):
    s1, s2 = s2, s1

distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
for i2, c2 in enumerate(s2):
    dist = [i2+1]
    for i1, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        if c1 == c2:
            dist.append(distances[i1])
        else:
            dist.append(1 + min((distances[i1], distances[i1 + 1], dist[-1])))
    distances = dist
return distances[-1]
```

You can get more informations about this distance on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).